# Refer to last result using Wolfram|Alpha Query

Tags: wolframalpha

how can I assign a name to the result using Wolfram|Alpha Query in order to use it in the next line of code?

`Solve[\[CapitalAlpha] == E + \[Beta]\[Lambda](\[Pi]+\[Beta]\[CapitalBeta]\[CapitalAlpha])/(1-\[Beta]+\[Beta]\[CapitalBeta])+\[Beta](1-\[Lambda])(\[Alpha]+\[Beta]\[CapitalChi]\[CapitalAlpha])/(1-\[Beta]+\[Beta]\[CapitalChi]), \[CapitalAlpha]]`

In the next line I want to set A equal to something.

Thank you for your help!

Comment: Can you please include an image of the formula.

Comment: I don't think this can be done directly in Wolfram|Alpha, but using Wolfram Desktop allows a lot more functionality. In Wolfram Desktop you can use % to get the result of the previous cell.